# How to debug a maven application after deploying it using tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am new to `maven` and `tomcat` . I have created  a project. After running, created  a jar file.So, I deployed it in the tomcat. Now It is running on my localhost properly.Now I have added one print statement in the code. So,where will this get printed , because I already deployed that jar file of the code. So, what is the way to debug an application after deploying it ?

Comment: https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging

Comment: try `catalina.out`  try debugging from with your IDE (Eclipse maybe)

Comment: I am using intellij.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options - either start tomcat from your IDE or use remote debugging. Here are some tutorials for you:

Intellij:

- [IntelliJ IDEA – Run / debug web application on Tomcat](https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-run-debug-web-application-on-tomcat/)
- [HOW TO REMOTELY DEBUG APPLICATION RUNNING ON TOMCAT FROM WITHIN INTELLIJ IDEA](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/)

Eclipse:

- [Debugging your Tomcat Webapp with Eclipse (remote debug)](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/tomcat-tcat-server/debugging-your-tomcat-webapp-with-eclipse/)
- [Launching and Debugging Tomcat in Eclipse](https://dzone.com/articles/launching-and-debugging-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Once you make changes to the code you will need to rebuild the project and redeploy. If you used 'System.out.println(..)' it will be printed out to the console. Where that ends up depends on how you run Tomcat.

You can enable remote debugging in the jvm that runs Tomcat. To do that edit the catalina.sh or catalina.bat it you are running under Windows. Add the following to the CATALINA_OPTS: '-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y'. You will then need to configure your IDE to connect to that remote debugging session. You did not say, which IDE are you using.

Comment: I am using intellij and my using ubuntu.,